# The site includes HTTP resources. but I did not find the http resource

Tags: tls

My website is https://blogviets.com but the https is not green. Chrome said "The site includes HTTP resources." but I have view the source of website and search for http:// and there is not resource such as image, css, js use http://

Could you please check and help me fix to make https green color?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the details offered in the message you get in the console:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://blogviets.com/' was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form which targets an insecure endpoint 'http://canthomoi.us10.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post'. This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection.

And it even points you to the line 90 where this problem happens:

```
<form class="thesis_email_form feat-box-mchimp" method="post" action="http://canthomoi.us10.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post">
```